# Links working on codepen do not work locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some issue with HTML links not working locally however they do work on Codepen.

I have 3 pages; when I run them locally the links work on the first two but do not show on the 3rd. The 3rd-page links do show up in Codepen.

I have tried for over a week now trying to figure it out.

This is the Codepen:

https://codepen.io/Randy3/pen/oPvQoY?editors=1100

Here is the code itself

```css
body {
  background-color: ;
}

#Captain {
  border-radius: 40%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin: 0px;
}

/* The navbar itself. */

nav ul {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  color: orange;
}

footer a {
  margin-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.figure-img {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 240px;
  max-height: 340px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  border: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="../profile.html/profile.html"> Home </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="../profile.html/profile.html"> Profile </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="../gallery.html/gallery.html"> Gallery </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <br>

  <h1> The works </h1>
  <br>

  <!--  <section class="figure-img">
    
        <figure class="photo">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ce/02/38/ce02382eed1d9b50fa50b4f4ee1f9600.jpg" alt="ying yang fish">
        </figure>
    
        <figure class="photo">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/18174/reflection-pad-gaming-gamepad.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="captain">
        </figure>
    
        <figure class="photo">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61gG0598btL._SX342_.jpg" alt="tophat">
        </figure>
    
        <figure class="photo">    
          <img src="https://img3.stockfresh.com/files/b/beaubelle/m/25/686513_stock-photo-love-bird-with-gift-box-vector.jpg" alt="battlelady">
        </figure>
    
        <figure>
          <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/naum100/naum1001510/naum100151000017/45714786-gear-hand-drawn-icon-vector.jpg?ver=6" alt="wiretree">
        </figure>
    
        <figure>
          <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/mosaic_250/2645560/1123343060/stock-photo-summer-quote-summer-vibes-1123343060.jpg" alt="fox">
        </figure>
      </section>
    -->
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Randy3/"> Codepen </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/randy_noms/"> Instagram </a>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Ps. If it helps the folders are as follows:

Desktop: (the folder is on my desktop) 
Foundations (the name of the project folder on the desktop)
Gallery.html ( the name of the html page) 
Gallery.html ( the name of the html document)

Comment: What do you mean by the links "don't work"? Are you getting an error, or a page not found? What is the 3rd page?

Comment: On the gallery page, the navigation  links do not show up at all when I run the page locally (on google chrome/firefox). the page loads, but the links are not visible at all. On codepen the links are visible for that page.

Comment: also @jeto thank you for replying.

Comment: On the codepen, the Gallery link points to https://codepen.io/boomerang/gallery.html/gallery.html which gives a 404.

Comment: I didn't post all of the html pages. I only posted the page that the links are not working on. I can all of the code  if that helps.

Comment: Try to inspect the links using your browser (usually right-click > Inspect Element). Can you see them in the HTML? If so, you should be able to figure out why it isn't showing up based on CSS code. It's hard to help you if we can't see it happen though.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you Jeto

Comment: Interestingly using inspect the links are not in the code at all for that page.

Comment: Well then they're probably not in your source file :)

Comment: Sorry to be a newb but what does that mean? I'm learning solo lol. Does that mean they are not in the root folder?

Comment: I mean your gallery.html file, when opened with your text editor or IDE, on the computer your website is hosted on (your own computer, if it's locally).

Comment: Ok I figured that part out lol. But on inspect they seem to be either "to high on the page" or invisible. In other words they show up on inspect now but hovering on them are are invisible on the page itself

Comment: Check the differences with the other pages then. CSS-wise and all. Again it's pretty much impossible to find what's wrong if we can't see it.

Comment: thank you very much. You have been a huge help Jeto

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck :)